# Redirect To another pages element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a One page Website. And I want to redirect to one om its elements from another page.
[link](http://www.betcartpartners.com/index.html#contact)
This works,but page jumps to top when its loaded. what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can used anchor and when you create a link to the expected part page refer to the anchor you have previously created. something in the spirit of the following.

First create the anchor one the page where you want to access

```
 <a name="youranchor"></a>
```

Then the link

```
<a href="http://yourOnePageSite#youranchor">link</a>
```